# In JQuery, how to make an action when choosing an input with a mouse click?

Tags: jquery

As you can see below, there is some history addresses that I chan choose in a formular, so when I choose one and press **"Enter"** the color will adapt (become green if it's a mail address, or stay red if it is not). I did this using this piece of code (JQuery):

```
  $( "#mail" ).keyup(function() {

    if(!validateEmail($("#mail").val())) {
        $("div.mail").removeClass("has-success");
        $("div.mail").addClass("has-error");
    }
    else{
      $("div.mail").removeClass("has-error");
      $("div.mail").addClass("has-success");
      }

    });
```

[image]

But the problem is if I click the "history" email address with the mouse instead of pressing "Enter", nothing happens (even if I choose the mail address). So I tried with other JQuery functions like `.mouseup()` or `.click()` but it still does not work.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#selector').focus(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

`focus` event fires when element get the focus either from mouse selection or from tab.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [jQuery.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method:

```
$( "#mail" ).change(function() {

    if(!validateEmail($("#mail").val())) {
        $("div.mail").removeClass("has-success");
        $("div.mail").addClass("has-error");
    }
    else{
        $("div.mail").removeClass("has-error");
        $("div.mail").addClass("has-success");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`blur`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/). This will fire when the element loses focus. Using `keyup` will fire every time a key is pressed, which is not what you want to do.

```
$( "#mail" ).on('blur', function() {
    if(!validateEmail($("#mail").val())) {
        $("div.mail").removeClass("has-success");
        $("div.mail").addClass("has-error");
    }
    else{
        $("div.mail").removeClass("has-error");
        $("div.mail").addClass("has-success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, it is not what I want, I need the color to change when I select an history item with the click.

Comment: A history item in an input box? Running this type of check on every keystroke is a little excessive. No matter what, they're not going start with a valid email address the first keystroke they make.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mail").on('keyup', function() {

    if (!validateEmail($("#mail").val())) {
      $("#mail").removeClass("has-success");
      $("#mail").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
      $("#mail").removeClass("has-error");
      $("#mail").addClass("has-success");
    }

  });

$('input').on('change', function() { 

    if (!validateEmail($("#mail").val())) {
        $("#mail").removeClass("has-success");
        $("#mail").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
        $("#mail").removeClass("has-error");
        $("#mail").addClass("has-success");
    }
});

  function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  }
});
```

```css
.has-success {
  border-color: green;
}

.has-error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input id='mail' value='' />
```

Comment: Hello, Run Snippet => click on input => select an history research with arrows => click on it with the mouth => it still red (instead of green)